# Is there a GUID generator in Visual Studio code with Ominpascal extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnipascal

When creating a new interface a GUID has to be added to the interface definition.
The Embarcadero IDE has a shortcut for this Ctrl-Shft-G

Does Visual Studio Code with the omnipascal extenson also have such a shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no dedicated shortcut for creating a GUID for an interface but it's always the first item in the code completion list when requested from inside an interface declaration without a GUID. The default shortcut in VSCode to request code completion is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>.

[image: Code completion for a new interface GUID]